# Node.js variable declaration and scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

When I type this in node.js, I get `undefined`.

```
var testContext = 15;
function testFunction() {
  console.log(this.testContext);
}
testFunction();
=>undefined
```

Without `var` keyword, it passes (=>15). It's working in the Chrome console (with and without `var` keyword).

Comment: Have you tried removing `this.` in your call to `console.log()`?

Comment: What's the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) doing there?

Comment: related: [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572)

Comment: @JustinNiessner removing `this.` works. why? If `testFunction();` is called in another node.js file, should it still work? (tested yes, but why?)

Comment: Found out it to be the `lexical scope` of javascript.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It doesn't work in Node when using `var` because `testContext` is a **local of the current module**. You should reference it directly: `console.log(testContext);`.

When you don't type `var`, what happens is that `testContext` is now **a global var in the entire Node process**.

In Chrome (or any other browser - well, I'm unsure about oldIE...), it doesn't matter if you use `var` or not in your example, `testContext` **will go to the global context**, which is `window`.

By the way, the "global context" is the default `this` of function calls in JS.

Comment: I know that it's probably of no practical use, probably, but is there a way to access the `globals` actual globals in the node? Just curious.

Answer (score 22):

The key difference is that all modules (script files) in Node.js are executed in their own [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) while Chrome and other browsers execute all script files directly within the global scope.

This is mentioned in the [Globals documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects):

> Some of these objects aren't actually in the global scope but in the module scope - this will be noted.

The `var`s you declare in a Node module will be isolated to one of these closures, which is why you have to [export members](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) for other modules to reach them.

Though, when calling a `function` without a specific context, it will normally be defaulted to the *global object* -- which is conveniently called [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) in Node.

```
function testFunction() {
    return this;
}

console.log(testFunction() === global); // true
```

And, without the `var` to declare it, `testContext` will default to being [defined as a global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488).

```
testContext = 15;
console.log(global.testContext); // 15
```

Comment: By "closure" and "scope" I think you mean "execution context".

Comment: @RobG They're still valid and commonly-used terms. But, yes, ECMA defines them as [Execution Contexts](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).

Comment: They are commonly use incorrectly, some other references: [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clClose), [scope](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clScCh) and [execution context](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clExCon).

Comment: @RobG I'm aware of what each are. But, the distinction is pedantic. Which is fine and I agreed with you about it. But, "*scope*" is still a valid term for describing the general concept while `[[Scope]]`, scope chains, and Execution Contexts are the more-specific implementation details.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

> var something inside an Node.js module will be local to that module.

So, it is going to be different as the `var testContext` is in module context and the context of this is `global`.

You can alternatively, use:

```
global.testContext = 15;
function testFunction() {
  console.log(this.testContext);
}
testFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has to do with the `this` key word. If you do `console.log(this)` you will see that testContext is not defined. You may want to try:

```
this.testContext = 15;
function testFunction() {
  console.log(this.testContext);
}
testFunction();
```