# What's the benefit to export functions with self invoke functions than direct return

Tags: javascript

I've checked a lot of codes and I've saw a lot of people doing

```
module.exports = (function(){
  return {
    functionA: function() {

      }
    },
    functionB: function() {

    }
  };
})();
```

so, why not just do

```
module.exports = {
  functionA: function() {

  },
  functionB: function() {

  }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Self invoke functions keep scope/context of inner functions in the first example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850234/node-js-variable-declaration-and-scope for more info about Node.js modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example allows you to hide variables within its own closure scope that can be shared with your return object's methods.  The For example, if you did the following...

```
var foo = (function(){
   var x = 2;
      return {
        addToTwo: function(y){
        return x + y;
      },
      subtractFromTwo: function(y){
        return x - y;
      }
   }
};
```

The above example shows that the `x` variable is protected and shared between `addToTwo` and `subtractFromTwo`.  The second example only will allow you to make `x` as part of the object without the same protection.

```
module.exports = {
  x: 3,
  functionA: function() {
     return this.x;
  },

};
```

`x` can be altered in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Those are exactly the same.  It's a stylistic decision.

According to the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) docs:

> Variables local to the module will be private, as though the module was wrapped in a function.

You could also do it this way:

```
module.exports.functionA = function() {

};

module.exports.functionB = function() {

};
```

Or:

```
// either method for creating a function works
function functionA () {}

var functionB = function () {} 

module.exports = {
    functionA : functionA,
    functionB : functionB
};
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's an informative answer. It doesn't really answer *why* people do that, but there's no good answer for that part of the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One of the greatest advantages of directly invoked functions is the use of [closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) which cannot be obtianed in a separate manner, so literally they are not the same.