# Global Variable Scope Not recognized in Node.js console

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, console, strict

So in a browser (chrome), if I run this code in the js console, the function call foo(); prints to the console the number 2.  But if I run it in node.js, the function call foo() prints *undefined*.  Why is this the case? Does node automatically run code in 'strict mode'?

```
function foo() {     
   console.log(this.a); 
} 

var a = 2; 

foo();
```

Comment: i tried in Node.js REPL, it does prints 2

Comment: Ah i see. in REPL it works. but running a file with this code called foo.js by typing "node foo.js" to the terminal  prints undefined. wondering why it does that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850234/node-js-variable-declaration-and-scope

Comment: that answers it. Thanks czheo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

> var something inside an Node.js module will be local to that module.

So, it is going to be different.

You can alternatively, try:

```
function foo() {     
   console.log(this.a); 
} 
global.a = 2; 

foo();
```