# Why this.bar returns a different result on webstorm ?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am learning Javascript and I am currently watching a lecture about it. One of the example in lecture like this;

```
function foo(){
    console.log(this.bar);
}

var bar = "bar1";
var o2 = { bar: "bar2", foo: foo};
var o3 = { bar: "bar3", foo: foo};

foo();     // bar1
o2.foo();  // bar2
o3.foo();  // bar3
```

This is work as intended in the comments when I try to run on Google Chrome console. But I am working on Webstorm and I realized foo(); returns **undefined**. It is probably foo(); doesn't called from global but why this is working like this on Webstorm. ECMAscript is 5.1 and I changed and tried on different versions but the result was same. Thank you for any help.

Webstorm console result;

```
undefined
bar2
bar3
```

Comment: In first case in browser, this refers to window and as `var bar` is defined in global context, it belongs to `window` this might not be the case in your IDE..

Comment: `foo` never returns anything but `undefined`. There is no `return` statement. Did you mean to say Chrome prints to the console and Webstorm does not?

Comment: @zvone No it does not relevant with console. I learned from answer that node.js files has own modules so var bar = .. etc. belongs to local module scope. Thats why I am taking different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not executing client-side JS, WebStorm is using node.js. The behaviour of that code is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850326/5695504).