# Why cant we see 'console' as a property of the 'global' object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We can we use `global.console.log('A')` should mean that console is a property of the global object. But using `console.log(global)`, I don't see any property named 'console' ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not enumerable, so it doesn't show up when just logging the plain `global` object. But it's still directly on `global`:

```
>global.hasOwnProperty('console')
true
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(global, 'console')
{
  value: {
    ...
  },
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
}
```

If you want to examine *all* properties on an object, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(global)
```

(There are *lots* of non-enumerable properties on `global`, and only a few enumerable ones)

Comment: What about the second question ?

Comment: Different questions should be separated into different posts, but the answer to your second question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850234/node-js-variable-declaration-and-scope - the top level of a module is *not* the global scope